# Android Eclipse OSX Creating AVD using Terminal launches AVD Manager

Tags: eclipse, macos, android-virtual-device

I'm new to programming and working with Eclipse on a Mac. I'm trying to create a new AVD with Google Maps Support and when launch 'android' (in the SDK tools folder) I get "No command line parameters provided, launching UI". This launches the Eclipse Android SDK and AVD manager.

My question is how do I create a new AVD with Google Maps support? All of the information I've found seems to use commands from terminal. My issue is when I try to use terminal it launches the AVD manage?

Any help is appreciated as I'm very new at this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with the GUI: Launch the AVD Manager by using the android command in the tools directory. In eclipse you can also access the tool from Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.

1. Click the "New" button to create a new AVD.
2. In the dialog that appears, specify a name for the AVD and select the system image target that you want the AVD to use. Select one of the **Google APIs (Google Inc.)** targets, making sure to choose a version whose API Level matches the android:minSdkVersion attribute in your application's manifest.
3. Configure the other options you want and then click "Create AVD".